# Badge Display Chooser badges incorrect color and not sticky

Tags: bug, design, badges, profile-page, mobile-web

With rev 2019.7.1.34183 the chooser for showing the manner in which our badges are to be displayed was changed from tabs to dropdown selector. On main Meta (with rev 2019.7.2.34187) it works correctly, on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/current) (for example) it's broken. Last time I used the older chooser it worked correctly (I don't know what version that was), it seems that there was an intervening version that was broken compared to older or newest.

Now all our badges are re-colored silver regardless of their true grade and it's not sticky, refreshing the page reverts to the default. I don't prefer the change of chooser but especially dislike the re-coloring and that it reverts.

I'm not opposed to going back to the way it was or fixing the way it is.

[image: Badge display format chooser]

Using Firefox Android 68.0b14 (Desktop Site) these sites are also affected: [Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current), [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/current), and [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/current), **but** [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/current) is **not** affected.

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverlow.com/users/current) ( which is rev 2019.7.2.34187, the same as main Meta) there's a mixture of behaviour: After clicking on a tab it changes to the dropdown chooser and shows all the badges incorrectly (different from main Meta) but after refreshing the page everything is partly fixed (back to having tabs and the choice you made sticks) and most importantly your badges are the correct color and sorting order. The only weird thing being the temporary switch from tabs to chooser and back, on main Meta it remains *tabs* throughout.

Comment: Can't reproduce it - which browser and OS? Also, it looks like the bronze & silver icon have been printed over each other. FWIW, I still have tabs instead of the dropdown, so it might be an A/B testing issue.

Comment: Ah, you're using the (old) mobile web on GD and the new responsive design on MSE. I can't reproduce the bug on iOS, and my Android device refuses to connect to WiFi here so I can't test that.

Comment: @Glorfindel, when I [visit ***your*** page the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLYiW.jpg) I see Tabs. When I [click on a different Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGbfe.jpg) it automagically changes to a chooser style.